# How to change image in button which is in listboxitem when fires some event?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, button

I'm making a page with `LongListboxSelector` which shows audiotracks. Each item has `Button` "play" and `TextBlock` with artist and title info. I'm using `BackgroundAudioPlayer`. My desire is to make **next**: when track is playing - image of the `Button` is "pause", when track is over - make its `Button` image "play", and make the next track's `Button` image "pause" (next track plays automatically). I tried somethink likes this

```
    public AudioListPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayStateChanged += Instance_PlayStateChanged;
    }

    void Instance_PlayStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Stopped)
        {
            IEnumerable buttons = AudioLLS.Descendants<Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.RoundButton>();
            var test = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));

            foreach (Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.RoundButton item in buttons)
            {                   
                if (item.ImageSource == test)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("in new image");
                    item.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/appbar.transport.play.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
                    buttons.GetEnumerator().MoveNext();
                    item.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Images/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

`PlayState.Stopped` fires when track ends, and next is going to start.
I tried to take all buttons in my LLS using `LinqToVisualTree` helper in `IEnumerable buttons = AudioLLS.Descendants<Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls.RoundButton>()` and compare their images with `test`. But as I can see - I'm doing it wrong, because in block `if(item.ImageSource == test)` my app never comes. Please, tell me, what I'm doing wrong? And if my way to solve the problem is bad - please, tell me how to do it in easy way.

Comment: It is difficult to say anything without XAML code. And you didn't post the code where you actually start or stop the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added two property to my audio model

```
    private bool isPlaing = false;
    public bool IsPlaing 
    { 
        get { return isPlaing; }
        set 
        { 
            isPlaing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsPlaing");
            if (IsPlaing) Image = @"/Images/appbar.transport.pause.rest.png";
            else if (!IsPlaing) Image = @"/Images/appbar.transport.play.rest.png";
        }
    }
    private string image = @"/Images/appbar.transport.play.rest.png";
    public string Image { get { return image; } set { image = value; OnPropertyChanged("Image"); } }
```

and in `playerStateChanged` i added

```
        if (BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.PlayerState == PlayState.Stopped)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < AudioList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (AudioList[i].Url1 == currTrack)
                {
                    AudioList[i].IsPlaing = false;
                    currTrack = AudioList[i + 1].Url1;
                    AudioList[i + 1].IsPlaing = true;
                    break;
                }

                }
            }
            BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Play();
        }
```

In this way I solved my problem. As I can see - all works fine.